# What the difference "latency time" VS "Connect Time" In Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am user jmeter 3.1
I am unclear the difference of "Latency time" vs "connected time",
In fact, in jmeter official document, it said :

**New connect time metric**

"connectTime " represents the time to establish connection. By default it is not saved to CSV or XML, to have it saved add to user.properties:

**jmeter.save.saveservice.connect_time=true**

[image]

So, what the mean of "latency time"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Connect Time**: time taken to establish TCP connection (at TCP layer in TCP/IP model) b/w client and server using TCP Handshake. If TCP Handshake is successful, then the client can send further requests (HTTP request - HTTP layer). If not, the client can't talk to the server. This can happen if the server is not live or busy responding other requests.

**Latency Time**: JMeter measures the latency from just before sending the request to just after the first response has been received. (`Connect time` is included while calculating `Latency Time`)

**Elapsed time**: JMeter measures the elapsed time from just before sending the request to just after the last response has been received

References:

1. https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html
2. http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPConnectionEstablishmentProcessTheThreeWayHandsh-3.htm

Comment: Does the Latency time - Connect time = Server Response time ?

Comment: server response time may be misleading. server processing time may be the right word to use. that is my opinion. i.e., `Latency time - Connect time = 
 server processing time`