# Jmeter connect time

Tags: tomcat, jmeter

I am testing a web application that runs on Tomcat9 using Jmeter5, in the result table I can see high connect time(8000 ms) for some of the requests, would that be because

1. Tomcat not able handle quickly(checked web application logs response time was under 2 seconds max)
2. Network
3. OS
4. All the above

How can narrow down further?

I understand connect time is time taken for TCP/IP handshake, from following links,

[Jmeter User manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)

[SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41790674/2151491)

Below are test details,

Threadgroup - 1(800 request/sec)

Users - 60000

Ramp up - 600

Loop - 1

HTTP request defaults - 8(jsp)

Using cookie manager and synchronizing timer

Machine configuration- 4 core processor, 8 GB RAM and runs on Windows 2012

Jmeter configuration - 2 GB heap space allocated

Answer (score 1):

This

```
Threadgroup - 1(800 request/sec) 
Users - 60000
```

in combination with this

```
high connect time(8000 ms) for some of the requests
```

and with assumption that you're running it on a single instance of JMeter - makes me suspect that you're just overwhelming your machine.

Would you please update the post with your running configuration, for both your machine & JMeter (if latter differs from standard)?

Meanwhile, here's what you can do for further investigations:

1) Monitor your JMeter-running machine's vital metrics realtime, as the tests are running. Watch for Network throughput especially, but CPU, Mem, other I/O as well.

2) Take a look into vital metrics specifically for JVM running your JMeter (with [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html), for instance, or other tools, there's handful of them) - look at heap usage stats, GC stats, etc.

3) Take the logs from your Tomcat & match the slow communication records in time for both sides. That may give you a clue who's gonna take the blame, server or JMeter.

4) Sniff the network communications (with Fiddler or any other tool of your choice). That would give you a detailed look into connection process.

P.S. Connection time in JMeter is not ONLY "time taken for TCP/IP handshake". That part is usually extremely fast, while following SSL handshake can make more notable difference.

Comment: Well, I see. I guess you got no other choice but to go for investigations I tried to outline. Start with p.3 & p.1, perhaps, to narrow the scope. Wish you luck with that.